# index.cfm append with SES URL in MURA

Tags: .htaccess, coldfusion, apache2.2, mura

Recently working with MURA CMS with RAILO on UBUNTU. I am installing MURA in inner folder of root directory.

public_html >> website.

Following code added in .htaccess to rewrite URL to run website without index.cfm and website directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
DirectoryIndex index.cfm
RewriteRule ^$ /website/ [R]
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}  !-d
RewriteRule ^website/([a-zA-Z0-9/-\s]+)$ /website/index.cfm/$1 [PT]
```

So my url http://example.com/website/privacy/ rewrite as
http://example.com/website/index.cfm/privacy/
I think rewrite rule should work correctly as I have tried some online validator and giving me correct result but if run it into MURA it produce URL like
   http://example.com/website/index.cfm/privacy/index.cfm

I am not sure who is adding last index.cfm (apache or mura) and this take me to 404 page everytime.

Please help... this driving me crazy..

Thanks,
Pritesh

**UPDATE**
I have same site setup with windows/IIS 7 under subfolder of root and work fine though, if that help

Comment: This may help http://www.stephenwithington.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/9/15/Removing-indexcfm-From-Mura-CMS-URLs-on-WindowsIIS7

Comment: @MattBusche, I am working Ubuntu and Apache server, so I need to use .htaccess instead of web.config. I have setup same kind of rule but only difference is added website at front since I have mura setup in website sub folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matt and Mael for spending time for this issue. 
Finally figure it out that TOMCAT was causing issue and adding index.cfm at the end.

```
<url-pattern>/website/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
```

Add above URL pattern in web.xml file and it start working fine.

Answer (score 2):

To take off index.cfm of the URL, you have to edit file `settings.ini.cfm`
To edit this file

1. go to Modules / File manager
2. Then tab `Application Root`
3. Select folder `config`
4. Then right click on settings.ini.cfm and edit
5. In this file, `siteidinurls` and `indexfileinurls` have to be at `0`

   siteidinurls=0
   indexfileinurls=0

After change, you have to reload application by clicking on `Reload application` on the `Settings` menu at the top of the window.

Comment: I already have both variable setup to zero but still doesn't work.